# How can I quickly switch format with RAW+JPEG images?

Tags: raw, darktable, raw-plus-jpeg

I have RAW+JPEG photos in Darktable. I have given some star rating to JPEG photos and filtered the lighttable view using the stars. While I have selected one of those JPEG images, can I quickly switch to its RAW counterpart?

Currently, I have to remember the image name, switch the view to ≥ 1 star and find it manually.

Darktable 2.4 groups each RAW+JPEG pair but I haven’t found any way to utilize the groups for switching images inside.

Why do I want this? Well, it’s a long story: I switched from iPhoto to Darktable while taking most images with Canon 50D. I appreciated the extended editing capabilities for RAW photos but when I export untouched RAW image from Darktable, I usually get a much worse result than what I was used to with iPhoto. The image produced by iPhoto was almost the same as the JPEG produced by the camera  (slightly better, actually). However, while Darktable uses the quite good camera JPEG preview on unedited RAW images, it does the default RAW processing for the slideshow mode or export – and it’s not really good at it actually. So I started to shoot RAW+JPEG and work with JPEG images basically unless I want to do advanced processing of an image. Then I switch to RAW and I’d like to do it quickly.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MichaelClark I mostly use macOS when working with photos.

Comment: Have you tried *Digital Photo Professional 4* for Mac? I'm pretty sure the latest versions support the 50D.

Comment: @MichaelClark No, I haven’t. However, isn’t it just RAW processing software? I like the concept of Darktable or iPhoto which allows organizing and non-destructive editing inside one application.

Comment: *DPP* has capabilities beyond raw processing, but that is the emphasis and strength of the app. There's a decent image review module that allows fairly quick review/rating of large numbers of raw image files. There are some organizational capabilities within *DPP*, but they are weak at best. But it does allow one to link a JPEG and raw version of the same file so that when a rating is given to one version it is also applied to the other. The 1-5 "star" ratings can be read by most other image handling applications. The 1-5 "check mark" ratings can not.